# Is id column position in Postgresql important?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I was testing a migration that deletes a primary key column id (I wanted to use a foreign key as primary key). When I ran and reverted the migration, I saw that the state of my table is the same, except that id column is now last one.

Will it change the behaviour of my database in any way and should I bother to restore the column order in the migration revert code?

Comment: The relative positions of the columns should have basically no affect on performance.  There might be some minor considerations due to alignment of fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that looks like an answer. Also, can you clarify what those minor considerations would be?

Comment: . . I'm not intimately familiar with the page layout of Postgres.  I don't know if it optimizes the column ordering based on alignment of fields with it (say, to eliminate gaps).  I hope someone with a bit more knowledge about the specific will answer.

Comment: The behaviour of the database will not change, however some poorly designed applications which use that database may crash - these applications that retrieve data using `SELECT *` instead of explicitly declare a list of columns `SELECT col1, col2, ...` and these that use `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (1,2,3,...)` instead of explicitely declaring field names `INSERT INTO (col1, col2 ...) VALUES (1,2,3,...)`. The "default" order of columns will change, and the application will fail. Anyway, this is not a problem of your database, but a problem of the application designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory everything should be fine, but there are always scenarios when your code could fail.

For example:

a)  [`blind insert`](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/07/what-is-a-sql-blind-insert/):

```
 INSERT INTO tab_name
 VALUES (1, 'b', 'c');
```

> **A blind insert is when an INSERT query doesn’t specify which columns receive the inserted data.**
>
> Why is this a bad thing?
>
> Because the database schema may change. Columns may be moved, renamed,
>   added, or deleted. And when they are, one of at least three things can
>   happen:
>
> 1. The query fails. This is the best-case scenario. Someone deleted a column from the target table, and now there aren’t enough columns for
>      the insert to go into, or someone changed a data type and the inserted
>      type isn’t compatible, or so on. But at least your data isn’t getting
>      corrupted, and you may even know the problem exists because of an
>      error message.
> 2. The query continues to work, and nothing is wrong. This is a middle-worst-case scenario. Your data isn’t corrupt, but the monster
>      is still hiding under the bed.
> 3. The query continues to work, but now some data is being inserted somewhere it doesn’t belong. Your data is getting corrupted.

b) [`ORDER BY oridinal`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY 1;
```