# Python Postgres Insert into error

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Hello all I have to make a bulk entry to my postgresql table from python for loop code. I have tried all possible means to enter the data. But I was unable to to do it.

```
        data = count,ipaddress,asn_value,asno,aso,sock_value,sock,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        print (data)
        cur.execute('insert into dataoldnew values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',data)
        print("Records created successfully")
        conn.close()
```

Debug

```
data= (1, '217.76.156.252', 1, 8560, '1&1 Internet SE', 0, 0, '2018-06-06 11:35')
```

Error

```
Exception in callback task2() at mining.py:43
handle: <Handle task2() at mining.py:43>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "mining.py", line 31, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mining.py", line 149, in task2
    cur.execute('insert into dataoldnew values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',data)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "217.76.156.252"
LINE 1: insert into dataoldnew values (1,'217.76.156.252',1,8560,'1&...
                                         ^
```

I have a table in postgresql.

Postgres Table Schema

```
-- Table: public.dataoldnew

-- DROP TABLE public.dataoldnew;

CREATE TABLE public.dataoldnew
(
  index bigint,
  idtemp bigint,
  ipaddress text,
  "timestamp" text,
  values_asn bigint,
  values_aso text,
  values_host_name text,
  values_host_name_true_false bigint
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.dataoldnew
  OWNER TO aditya;

-- Index: public.ix_dataoldnew_index

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_dataoldnew_index;

CREATE INDEX ix_dataoldnew_index
  ON public.dataoldnew
  USING btree
  (index);
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: `idtemp bigint,` and actual value `'217.76.156.252'`. Anyway [blind insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844860/5070879) is common antipattern.

Comment: `idtemp bigint,` change to text

Comment: I have created an index

Comment: You should add column names in sql statement. Like `insert into dataoldnew (id, ip) values (%s, %s)`

Comment: Thanks it worked @NobbyNobbs