# How Oracle insert statement work

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a tableX with the following columns accordingly -
`id | name | description | contact_no`

Now if I perform an insert operation
`insert into tableX(id, contact_no, name, description) value(?,?,?,?)`

**[note the order of the coulmns]**

In which order oracle will insert each column values?
i) according to the `insert` statement
ii) according to the column order in the tableX
iii) or oracle sort the columns alphabetically `[id, contact_no, description, name]` and put them accordingly.

Comment: Just wondering - why (option iii) would you think it might be alphabetical? Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Hibernate does that sorting while persisting. I wondered if oracle does that sort of thing underneath!

Comment: @JeffreyKemp let me explain the scenario I've faced,  In one of my `domain` I had a property named `description` which data type was `LOB`. There were some other fields after `description` whose data type were primitive types. While performing `persist` operation I got **ORA-24816** exception. To solve this error I took a way around by renaming the field name to `zzzDescription` which led hibernate to put this field at the end of inset query.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with sorting the column names alphabetically. Sounds like something weird with Hibernate, which tends to be a whole problem of its own...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp its the problem of **oracle**. Oracle can't insert a row having any **clob** data before any primitive types. the exact error I got was *Otherwise ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column is thrown*

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the way the values are *bound*. Oracle has no intrinsic restrictions on the order of the columns in an insert statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will put values based on column list:

```
insert into tableX(id, contact_no, name, description)
                -- 1st 2nd         3rd   4th
values(1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th);
```

If you omit column list then you will get ["blind insert"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844860/5070879)(common anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

According to the column you specified in the insert from left to right

```
insert into tableX(id, contact_no, name, description) value(1,2,3,4)
```