# ORA-01722! Why can't I INSERT a NUMBER into a NUMBER data field without getting this error?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone tell me what is going on here?

So I have a simple table location and it only has two columns; one is a number and the other varchar2.

I'm simply trying to insert some data into the locations table so I can get cracking with the other larger datasets but keep getting this damn error every time.

```
Error starting at line : 7 in command -
INSERT INTO location
VALUES (1, 'Head Office')
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

NOTE: Before down-voting, YES - I have seen others posting about this but is usually for something less obvious than my situation where they are trying to enter a string into a number field or a number into a string field!

In my case however, the data in the INSERT statement is a number AND the data type is also NUMBER!

DATA STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE location(
    locID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    locName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);
```

INSERT STATEMENT:

```
INSERT INTO location
VALUES (1, 'Head Office');
```

The error code can be seen above there where I first mentioned it.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. It may be worth mentioning that the ID field in 'location' table is being used as a FOREIGN KEY in a separate table 'employees'. I have however, checked that the data types matched!

EDIT #1: I'm using ORACLE SQL Developer

Comment: Always specify the column names on an INSERT. Repeat after me: "Always specify the column names on an INSERT".

Comment: Trigger on the table?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Sorry, I'm not a well rounded SQL developer (yet). Could you elaborate on the trigger?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, I understand I removed it as a form of error checking. Thanks for your input

Comment: Joe is asking whether the table has any triggers.

Comment: The table creation and `insert` as posted work fine, so there must be something different about your actual table and/or code.

Comment: It has even own name: [blind insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843901/is-id-column-position-in-postgresql-important/49844860#49844860) and it's common anti pattern

Answer (score 2):

Always include the columns when doing an `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO location (locId, locname)
    VALUES (1, 'Head Office');
```

From your description of the problem, this should not actually fix it.  This is just a good habit.

The above is correct SQL for your table.  If the error continues to happen it is probably coming from a trigger on the table.

Comment: Thanks, Wilco!! I did initially have the columns listed individually but removed them as an alternative to bashing my head off the wall repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

Think like its stupid, you are getting number error from "**head office**" not from **1**. Actually you are trying to insert string into number.
If you dont want to write column names to insert you should totally define all values in insert **in place** as located in table. I assume your table structure is

```
locId|locNumber
```

So your insert should be like below

```
insert into table values (1,'head office')
```

I hope you understand shortcut logic