# Why does 'INSERT INTO TABLE' fail but 'INSERT INTO TABLE (VALUES)' works

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a large table in one database and would like to "copy" a handful of columns to another table in another database, both databases on the same server (SQL Server 2012). I've created the "target" table using datatypes and definitions from the "source" table, and then try:

```
INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
SELECT ColumnA, 
       ColumnB,
       ColumnC,
       ColumnD
FROM [MYotherDB].[dbo].[MYotherTABLE]
```

This results in an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

However, the following works. Why?

```
INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE] (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD)
SELECT ColumnA, 
       ColumnB,
       ColumnC,
       ColumnD,
FROM [MYotherDB].[dbo].[MYotherTABLE]
```

Comment: Blind insert is common antipattern - define column list explicitly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844860/5070879

Comment: Because you are either inserting into the wrong columns, or maybe the order of the columns in your table does not line up with the order in the select clause.  _Always_ explicitly list out the target columns for an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Comment: "Antipattern alert" - that's awesome. I'm making a mental note. Thanks, Lukasz.

Comment: Why then, does the following work just fine?                                       INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
SELECT top (1000) ColumnA, 
       ColumnB,
       ColumnC,
       ColumnD
FROM [MYotherDB].[dbo].[MYotherTABLE]

Answer (score 1):

Because the definitions of `[MYDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]` and `[MYotherDB].[dbo].[MYotherTABLE]` aren't the same.

When performing an `INSERT`, the aliases/names of columns in the `SELECT` are meaningless to the destination table. Take, for example these 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (C1 int,
                     C2 int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.T2 (C1 int,
                     C2 int);
```

And let's put some data in `T1`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 (C1,
                    C2)
VALUES(1,2),(3,4);
```

Now, if we run these 2 statements:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T2
SELECT C2, C1
FROM T1;

INSERT INTO dbo.T2 (C2,C1)
SELECT C2, C1
FROM T1;
```

Do you think those 2 statements are identical? if so, you would be wrong:

```
SELECT *
FROM T2;
```

Notice that the values (from the first statement) where "switched" around. That's because the first statement was equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T2 (C1,C2)
SELECT C2, C1
FROM T1;
```

The same applies as well to if we were to switch the columns around in the definition of the table (what I suspect is the case in your environment):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T3 (C2 int,
                     C1 int);

INSERT INTO dbo.T3
SELECT C1, C2
FROM T1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.T3
```

We don't know the definitions of your tables, but the reason is the same. Solution: Always explicitly define your columns when using an `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks, Lamu. I get it what you're saying - that switching columns around could result in an error because wants to stuff the first argument into the first column. But I didn't switch them around. I also accept Lukasz ands Tim's "best practice" advice ... what threw me off was the type of error I was getting above, which sounded more like a datatype issue, in which case it didn't make sense to me that INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES () should be successful.