# How to only insert one column into a SQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a value into only one column. How can I do this without requiring to enter in all other columns' values?

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DbHelp.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Player_Data VALUES (?)", db.getConnection());
                ps.setString(1, e.getPlayer().getUniqueId().toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();
```

I use this to add a column to the existing table:

```java
String updateTable = "ALTER TABLE Player_Data ADD COLUMN " + name + " int(10) NULL;";
```

I expected this to only insert into the table on the first value and leave the others as null. But I actually recieve this error message: 
`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table Player_Data has 3 columns but 1 values were supplied)`

I understand that it's asking me to input values for the multiple columns but I need to only insert it into one and leave the rest as null or preferably have a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid ["blind inserts"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844860/5070879) and explicitly specify column list:

```
INSERT INTO Player_Data(column_name) VALUES (?);

-- this would work as long as other columns has:
-- identity property/default constraint/nullable
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the explanation. This has fixed my issue