# Is it possible to shorten a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one a SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO `t1`(col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM `t2`

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT*FROM `t1`

    WHERE (
        t1.col1 = t2.col1
    AND
        t1.col2 = t2.col2 )
 );
```

This query compares two existing tables "t1" and "t2".
Inserts data from table “t2” into table “t1” without any duplicate records between the two tables.
How can I truncate this SQL query? Can it be written in another way? Easier?

Comment: Yes. This my SQL query works correctly. I'm learning. I am looking for more solutions to get the most experience, so I ask here. @ Marios Nikolaou

Comment: Your query is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, correlated suqbuery could be rewritten as `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 -- I suggest to explicitly list all columns
SELECT t2.*
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1   -- USING (col1, col2) -- instead of ON clause
  ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 
WHERE t1.col1 IS NULL;
```

Related: [Blind insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844860/5070879)

Comment: You can also make it slightly shorter with `USING (col1, col2)`

Comment: Can you give one example with your solution? Please? Thank you. @ Bill Karwin

Comment: Copying data using the LEFT JOIN clause is great! Thank you!! @Lukasz Szozda

Comment: @PetrFořtFru-Fru . . . I don't see any advantage to using a `left join` instead of `not exists`.

Comment: Can you please explain your claim? Why `NOT EXIST` is better than `LEFT JOIN` ? What are the advantages and disadvantages of both SQL queries? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @PetrFořtFru-Fru . . . They are generally equivalent (under some circumstances in some databases one might be slightly better or worse than the other).  Your original query is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If (col1,col2) is a unique key in t1, you can just

```
insert ignore into t1 select * from t2;
```