# Identity column in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A simple question in Snowflake. I created a table with an identity column.

```
create table etl_test 
(id int identity,
name string);
```

And tried to insert data into it. In my SQL Server world, I just need to provide the value for the name field.

```
insert into etl_test values('test');
```

I tried the same in Snowflake but I am getting an error

> SQL compilation error: Insert value list does not match column list expecting 2 but got 1

How can I make sure that the value 'test' is inserted with id = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the column name(s) you are using if you aren't inserting into all the columns:

```
insert into etl_test (name) values('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

["Blind inserts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843901/is-id-column-position-in-postgresql-important/49844860#49844860) are antipattern regardless of RDBMS.

In your scenario, you need to specify column list and either remove id from column list or provide a `DEFAULT` for it.

```
INSERT INTO etl_test(id, name) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'test');
```